# A High School student time travelled through a certain time in Medieval Ages how would he/she survive?

Tags: time-travel, history, ancient-history

Since it's the Medieval Age can mean any time period and any place you can suggest which place and time the student can most likely survive with limited skill.
How would a person with high-school education survive in a medieval setting?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is an off-topic [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4868/40609). HCQs violate the [help/on-topic]'s rule, "When asking questions keep in mind that the goal of the site is to help you build your world, not to tell your story" because the answer is far to plot-based (e.g. VTC:Too Story-Based). Please read the first two bullet pages in the [help].

Comment: So... you want a reality-check on a time travelling high school student landing somewhere in medieval times, and then changing into an overpowered God ? How would this student not survive ? he has become a God now (??) I propose you remove the first sentence, it does not bear any relation to the title, or your question. If you don't like my edit, you can undo it.

Comment: This question is too broad and unspecific. Survival options will greatly vary depending on the location (landing in Europe would be vastly different from landing in Asia or Africa), time (Medieval Age lasted about 1000 years), and gender of the time traveller. Please also note that high school educational standards are different in different countries. For example, general education which is considered part of college education in the US is included in the high school curriculum in the EU.

Comment: A high school student can have more or less knowledge and skills depending on what specific high school they are from and in what grade they were when they left for the Mid-Evil world. So what is it? A 9th grade (1st high-school year) high-schooler from Alabama playing collision-ball, or a 12th grade (final high school year) high-schooler from France preparing for a *baccalauréat scientifique*?

Comment: Oh, and this is the third time today that I'll be removing the [tag:reality-check] tag because it's not being used properly. The tag's wiki explains everything, but a nice summary comes from the [help/on-topic], "Reality Check: Provide the relevant details of your world and a situation and we will make sure it remains internally consistent."

Comment: I would have suggested we vote to close as well, but for different reasons. First, there's no way to determine which answer is better. Second, it's so broad: Medieval period could mean anything from 500-1500 CE. And that's made worse by not narrowing it down to a country, because even in a certain year, cultures and countries vary so wildly that they might as well be on different planets. Then there's the skills of the MC, what are they? Even if you take two students from the same class, that won't guarantee the same answer.

Comment: On top of the above-mentioned reasons? If the answer is so complex I could write a book about it... that's another VTC reason. There are so many variables that each user here could write a dissertation on it, and each come to vastly different conclusions. And there'd still be no way for anyone to vote on 'the best', because there'd be no criteria to base 'best' on.

Comment: Bill and Ted would get you your answer. Of course, they had other help as well...

Comment: @AlexP -- Votes me the collision baller! Any kind of sport or physical activity of that sort means relatively good health and strength --- put a weapon in his hands and train him up for the army! Or put a tool in his hand and get him to work.